# yii datepicker is not displaying for some reason after using different theme

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker

I am using this datepicker widget it works fine when i do not use any theme and remain on the default theme of the yii. Recently i downloaded HEBO theme of yii from an online website but after applying that theme whenever i click on date field somethings happens in the background but unable to display the calender...

Is it because of Z-Index? or something else? Kindly advice me how to display this widget properly

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
  //  'name'=>'publishDate',
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'issue_date',
    // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'height:100px;'
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was something with the version of jquery , so i have update the jquery version to the current latest one and everything started working fine now.